# Making Jbuilder work with Rails 5 API Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use Jbuilder with Rails 5.0.0.beta1.1 in API mode. Out of the box, it doesn't work, even when creating the app/views directory.

For example, I have:

```
# app/controllers/tests_controller.rb
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  # The requests gets inside the action
  def test
  end
end

# app/views/tests/test.json.jbuilder
json.test "It works!"
```

The error I'm getting is

`No template found for TestsController#test, rendering head :no_content`

I guess I have to change some things in the config files. What do I have to do?

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: There's an issue open here: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/317

Answer (score 9):

Doing an explicit render from the controller like this works:

```
render 'controller_name/action.json.jbuilder'
```

Answer (score 4):

With API mode.

You need include module like bellow

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender # if you need render .jbuilder
  include ActionView::Layouts # if you need layout for .jbuilder
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, but in my case I had simply forgotten to add the jbuilder gem in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```